# Need to set an adapter to a ListView inside a DialogFragment but I get a null pointer exception with the getView() method? Why?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog which extends DialogFragment:

```
public class MyCustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

static MyCustomDialogFragment newInstance() {
    return new MyCustomDialogFragment();
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.institutional_info_custom_list, container, false); 
    return view;
}
}
```

And this is where I use this dialog (it is inside an onclick listener):

```
MyCustomDialogFragment newFragment = MyCustomDialogFragment.newInstance();
                View DialogView = newFragment.getView();
                DetailListView = (ListView) DialogView.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_list);
                final MasterDetailArrayAdapter adapter = new MasterDetailArrayAdapter(ComeHaInvestito.this, MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList);         
                DetailListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "master_detail_dialog");
```

MasterAndDetailstatitiscsInfoList is a list I am using with my custom ArrayAdapter, but the problem is with the View of the DialogFragment: it is null! Why? I read the android documentation and they say that getView() returns the View of the dialog which is the one returned by the onCreateView() overriden method.

So why I get a null pointer exception when trying to revocer the ListView which is in the dialogFragments layout???

Sorry but this does not make sense to me. An explanation will be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: the `getView()` method will return `null` until `onCreateView()` is called. and if you want to set the `Adapter` to your `DetailsListView`, set it in `onCreateView()` or inside `onViewCreated()` method of `Fragment`...

Comment: Thanks you have been really clear! Now I understand this but how can I pass my custom list of custom objects ( MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList) to the dialogFragment's methods onViewCreated() or onCreateView()?

Comment: For that blackbelts answer will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Use `setArguments()` to provide the dataset for the `Adapter` to the `DialogFragmet`. In `DialogFragment` override `onViewCreated()`, retrieve the `ListView`, create the Adapter and set it to the `ListView`

Comment: How can I pass my customlist (MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList) to the DialogFragment and use it in the onViewCreated() or onCreateView()?

Comment: So I don't have to pass List of custom objects but just the adapter? But again, sorry, I am new in android and I have never had to deal with fragments. Is there a method of the Bundle object or something?